# memory consumption in deb9 vs deb10

Tags: c++, memory, debian

In the below c++ program I am trying to divide a bigger memory block into smaller subblock by moving pointers by 1 page. While creating a subblock I am initializing the variable of a structure which is of 64 bits. I tried to run this code on debian10 and debian9. What I observed is in deb9 only 64 bits memory is consumed but  deb10 consumes the entire page which is off 4K.
Can someone help me understand what causes this difference? Can this be related to the way the kernel handles the memory? Thanks for your help in advance.

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned char u8;
typedef unsigned int u32;
typedef unsigned long long u64;

struct e{
   u8* f;
   u64* s;
};
struct se{
   u64 cid;
   void* np;
};
const u64 a = -1;
u32 subchunk = 2878;
u32 subchunkperchunk = 140;
u32 chunksize = 1028096;   //in bytes
u32 TSize = 4096;
u32 eleOfChunk = 50;
u32 eSize = 4096;
u64 x;
vector<e> v;
int it=0;

u64& add(const void* ep)
{
    void* subChunkPtr = (void*) (((u64)ep) / chunksize * chunksize);
    u64 firstElementLocation = ((u64)subChunkPtr) + TSize;
    u32 indexInsideSubChunk = (((u64)ep)-firstElementLocation) / eSize;
    se* elePtr = ((se*)subChunkPtr) + indexInsideSubChunk;
    return elePtr->cid;
}

int main()
{
    int file = open("Result", O_CREAT|O_WRONLY, S_IRWXU);
    dup2(file, 1);
    for (u32 i=0; i<= subchunk/subchunkperchunk; i++)
    {
      u32 eleInCurrChunk;
      if (i != subchunk/subchunkperchunk)
      {
         eleInCurrChunk = subchunkperchunk;
      }
      else
      {
         eleInCurrChunk = subchunk % subchunkperchunk;
         if (eleInCurrChunk == 0)
         {
            break;
         }
      }
      u32 CSize = (eleInCurrChunk+1) * chunksize;
      u8* sp;
      sp = new u8[CSize];
      u8* ssp = sp + (chunksize - ((u64)sp % chunksize));
      for (u32 j = 0; j < eleInCurrChunk; ++j)    //creat block
      {
         u8* scp = ssp + j * chunksize;
         u8* ep = scp + TSize;
         for (u32 k=0; k < eleOfChunk ; ++k)   //creat subblock
         {
             v.push_back(e());
             v[it].f = ep;
             v[it].s = &add(ep);
             add(ep)= a;               //set the 64 bits to high
             ep += eSize;
             ++it;
        }
        system("free -m");
      }
    }
  return 0;
}
```

```
Below is the output of the code on deb10
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:    7914        1789        4306           0        1819        5826
Swap:         0           0           0
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:    7914        1789        4306           0        1819        5826
Swap:         0           0           0
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:    7914        1791        4304           0        1819        5824
Swap:         0           0           0
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:   7914        1791        4304           0        1819        5824
Swap:        0           0           0
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:     7914        1793        4302           0        1819        5822
Swap:         0           0           0
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:    7914        1793        4302           0        1819        5822
Swap:         0           0           0
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:   7914        1795        4300           0        1819        5820
Swap:         0           0           0
.
.
.
Mem:       7914        4592        1502           0        1819        3022
Swap:           0           0           0
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:   7914        4594        1500           0        1819        3020
Swap:       0           0           0
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:    7914        4594        1501           0        1819        3021
Swap:        0           0           0
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:    7914        4596        1499           0        1819        3019
Swap:        0           0           0
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:     7914        4596        1499           0        1819        3019
Swap:           0           0           0
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:    7914        4598        1497           0        1819        3017
Swap:         0           0           0

If you check the memory usage on "used"  it is consuming ~4.5G by the end of the iteration.


Below is the output of the code on deb9.
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:   7923        1843        4128           4        1951        5776
Swap:       0           0           0
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:   7923        1843        4128           4        1951        5776
Swap:       0           0           0
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:   7923        1843        4128           4        1951        5776
Swap:        0           0           0
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:    7923        1843        4128           4        1951        5776
Swap:         0           0           0
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:     7923        1843        4128           4        1951        5776
Swap:          0           0           0
.
.
.

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:    7923        1870        4101           4        1952        5750
Swap:         0           0           0
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:    7923        1870        4101           4        1952        5750
Swap:         0           0           0
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:   7923        1870        4100           4        1952        5750
Swap:        0           0           0
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:     7923        1870        4100           4        1952        5750
Swap:         0           0           0
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:    7923        1870        4101           4        1952        5750
Swap:       0           0           0
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:     7923        1870        4100           4        1952        5750
Swap:         0           0           0
```

By the end of the iteration it is consuming ~1.8G
As we see from the output  there is a huge memory consumption difference between deb9 and deb10. I would like to know why this is different, when the same code runs on different Debian machines (i.e. deb9 and deb10).

Comment: You should allocate aligned memory: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/aligned_alloc And pick better names for your variables and structure members and add a few comments. The code is unreadable and my first guess would be that you are rounding wrong somewhere and the alignment of allocated memory just happens to be different between deb9 and deb10.

Comment: Also look into placement new and construct_at / destroy_at to create your structures. Using `cstdint` would also help. Are all those global variables actually variable? Shouldn't they all be `const` or enums? I can't imagine changing TSize at runtime would go over well.